# What is an elegant way to catch multiple exceptions without catching generic exceptions?

Tags: apex, exception, try-catch, type

I don't want to catch generic exceptions, but I want to handle all the exceptions I want to catch exactly the same way.

For arguments sake, lets say the code is:

```
try {
   doSomething();
}
catch(AException ex) {
   handleException();
}
catch(BException ex) {
   handleException();
}
catch(CException ex) {
   handleException();
}
/* ... */
catch(ZException ex) {
   handleException();
}
```

Is there an elegant way to express this?

I thought about creating a variable

```
Set<Type> exceptionsToHandle = new Set<Type>{
   AException.class, 
   BException.class, 
   CException.class, 
   /* ... */
   ZException.class 
}
try {
   doSomething();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
  if (exceptionsToHandle.contains(getType(ex)) {
       handleException();
  }
  else {
      throw ex;
  }
}
```

Except there is a fundamental problem: We have no way to actually get the exception's Type outside of ugly trial and error code which will be as inelegant as the problem I'm trying to solve.

Alternatively, I could make a set of strings and then check the class name for the instance of the Exception, but I'd rather have a typesafe solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: getTypeName won't work for you?

Comment: @Girbot, I'd rather a typesafe solution, so I want the Type, not a string of its name.

Comment: @BrianKessler Did you check my answer already. Should be a solution. Hope you find it more elegant than the standard code.

Comment: @BrianKessler you should also have a look at this similar Java question and how it uses polymorphism in the handle methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112976/java-polymorphic-behavior-weirdness-in-catch-block-explaination-needed

Comment: @RobertSösemann, thanks for the response, but that wasn't really what I was looking for.  Adrian Larson's answer below was exactly what I wanted.  That said, your link has useful and interesting information... I'd scratched my head over similar issues in the past.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can still support concrete types with `getTypeName` by using the `Type.forName` method.

```
Set<Type> allowlist = new Set<Type> { DmlException.class, ListException.class };
try
{
    // do stuff
}
catch (Exception pokemon)
{
    if (!allowlist.contains(Type.forName(pokemon.getTypeName()))
    {
        throw pokemon;
    }
    // actual error handling logic here
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, cheers!

Answer (score 4):

It's doable with an `abstract` base class as shown below.

```
public abstract class CustomException extends System.Exception {

}
```

Implementing exception classes

```
public class AException extends CustomException {

}


public class BException extends CustomException {

}
```

This test proves that it works

```
@IsTest
private class CustomException_Test {

    @IsTest
    private static void genericHandling() {

        Boolean aCatched = false;
        Boolean bCatched = false;
        Boolean othersIgnored = true;

        try {
            throw new AException();
        }
        catch(CustomException cex) {
            aCatched = true;
        }

        try {
            throw new BException();
        }
        catch(CustomException cex) {
            bCatched = true;
        }

        try {
            throw new NotACustomException();
        }
        catch(CustomException cex) {
            othersIgnored = false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            othersIgnored = true;
        }

        System.assert(aCatched);
        System.assert(bCatched);
        System.assert(othersIgnored);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very creative. I like it! Doesn't work if any of the exception types you want to catch are standard though.

Comment: True. But then he could use Polymorphism. Provide a version of handleException(Type ex) for each required type and one for generic Exceptions that basically does nothing.

Comment: Good answer.  I thought to do something similar with interfaces, but SFDC wouldn't seem to let an Exception implement anything.   Also, as @Adrian Larson observed, it can be a problem if I want to catch some standard exceptions, or similarly if I have Exceptions which are already extending some other base since Apex doesn't allow multiple inheritance.